# Final Fantasy 12 - Zodiac job - healing power

Tags: final-fantasy-12

Playing on PS2

In my party I only have

- white mage
- breaker
- black mage
- samurai
- uhlan
- hunter

The only person who can heal and remove status impairments is my white mage.  Did I make a mistake not including a red mage or knight?

My white mage is 10 levels higher than the others due to always being in the party.

edit:

I'm sure I can finish the game with this, but am I missing out?  Should I restart with a more balanced party?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I'm having trouble making sense of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated.  Basically I don't know if worth starting over with a more balanced party.

Comment: It's still not very clear at all.  Are you talking about the gambit system?  FF12 has specific characters, so listing classes doesn't really work very well.

Comment: ff12 - zodiac job system version has classes.  12 of them.  If you select the "white mage" class you get the license board with specific licences on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's worth restarting to get different classes. Items are **really** powerful in this game because they have no startup time, and the essential recovery items are eventually buyable. (Gil is pretty easy to get, especially once you've finished the license grids and can leave Cat-Ear Hoods equipped on your inactive party members.)

Your Shikari (Hunter) gets all 3 Remedy Lores, so Remedies used by him (Balthier, I assume) can cure practically all status effects, even a few that Esuna doesn't work on. Bushi and Uhlans also get Remedy Lore 1 and 2, which cover everything but Stop, Doom, and Disease (which are not too common). Of course everyone can also use the targeted status recovery items, which are usually sufficient.

Your Shikari also gets 3 Potion Lores, which greatly increases the amount of healing gained from Potions, Hi-Potions, and X-Potions when he uses them. (The Uhlan gets 2 Potion Lores, which also helps, and can get the 3rd from Famfrit, but your Black Mage probably needs the health instead.) Equipping a Phoenix Netsuke also doubles the effect of these items (and Phoenix Downs).

Your Uhlan receives 2 Phoenix Lores, which increases the amount of health people receive when revived by a Phoenix Down. The Shikari can also get 2 Phoenix Lores if you give him Ultima, but your Foebreaker gets Swiftness from Ultima, which is much better.